# Using COALESCE to return META title value with page information for navigation array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I am creating a multisite CMS with codeigniter and am having trouble with a query for navigation links.  Each page can have meta values that override the defaults `(location_id = 0)` with ones specific to the site if set.  I have two tables `cms_pages` and `cms_page_meta` storing the information.  Below is the relevant data

```
Table cms_pages
    page_id


Table cms_page_meta
    meta_id
    location_id
    page_id
    tag_name
    tag_value
```

I would like to do this in one call if feasible.

This is the call I was using, it causes pages to be listed twice if a title value exists for all locations `(location_id = 0)` and a specific location `(location_id = x)` where I just want the specific location if it exists otherwise the generic, otherwise NULL

```
SELECT cms_page.*, cms_page_meta.tag_value
FROM cms_pages
LEFT JOIN cms_page_meta ON cms_page_meta.page_id = cms_pages.page_id
WHERE cms_page_meta.location_id IN (0, x)
ORDER BY cms_pages.page_order`
```

I'm pretty sure I should to use coalesce but just can't figure out how to implement it.  Am I trying to do too much at once?  Should I split the calls and process with PHP array_merge?  I'd like to avoid that as I can cache the call and delete/regenerate the cache whenever I make a change to the pages or metadata.  The server gets ~10,000 hits a day so speed is helpful but not necessary yet...

I changed the above query so it only grabs generic data for right now.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use something like this:

```
SELECT
  cms_page.*,
  COALESCE(cms_pm2.meta_id, cms_pm1.meta_id) as meta_id,
  COALESCE(cms_pm2.tag_name, cms_pm1.tag_name) as tag_name,
  COALESCE(cms_pm2.tag_value, cms_pm1.tag_value) as tag_value
FROM
  cms_pages LEFT JOIN cms_page_meta cms_pm1
  ON cms_pm1.page_id = cms_pages.page_id
     AND cms_pm1.location_id = 0
  LEFT JOIN cms_page_meta cms_pm2
  ON cms_pm2.page_id = cms_pages.page_id
     AND cms_pm2.location_id = x      
ORDER BY cms_pages.page_order
```

Comment: Cool, similar to what I finally found.  I think using coalesce on the `meta_id` and `tag_name` is not necessary (mostly because I'm not using those values :) ) but may be good for someone else.  This query is being used to populate a navigation array and I wanted to get the page title as set in metadata for all the pages.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vortextangent you're welcome! yes it's almost the same as yours... it should be okay :) and yes you could add a third default value in COALESCE just in case both values are null

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution

```
SELECT cms_pages.*, coalesce(s.tag_value, g.tag_value, 'Coming Soon!') as tag_value
from cms_pages
left join cms_page_meta s on ad_pages.page_id = s.page_id and s.tag_name = "title" and s.location_id = 255
left join cms_page_meta g on ad_pages.page_id = g.page_id and g.tag_name = "title" and g.location_id = 0
WHERE `cms_pages`.`page_group_id` =  '5'
AND `page_type` =  1
ORDER BY `cms_pages`.`page_order`
```

Is this good performance-wise?